# Map hover & on click on Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is it possible for the map markers on Google maps that show 3/4/5 etc which make users zoom in on the map. is there an ability to add an 'on hover' that doesn't change the on click behaviour?

imagine you hover mouse over a 3 on the map and have a popup to say the destinations shown when you do click on the 3

Does Google maps support a separate on hover vs on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does.  Firstly on the Map itself there's `mouseover` and `mousemove` events which are basically doing the same thing:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map

Secondly if you wanted this only to happen on markers, on the Marker there's also `mouseover` and `mouseout` events, when a user hovers over a marker, then moves the cursor off the marker

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker

So you could do something like

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 51.476706, lng: 0},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {lat: 51.476706, lng: 0}
});


marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    // open your popup window
});

marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    // close your popup window
});
```